# Differentiating the composition of a multivariate function with dependency

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

This issue comes from a solution approach of a differential equation, but I encountered several times, not sure how to deal with it.
The concrete problem (related to the wave equation) is:

Let $u: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$, $ (x,t) \mapsto u(x,t)$ be the function we look for and define for $X = \alpha x + \beta t$ and $T = \gamma x + \mu t$ the function $U$ via the condition $U(X,T) = u(x,t)$.

Now the instruction is to write the derivatives $\partial^2_{tt} u$ and $\partial^2_{xx} u$ as functions of $U$. Since they are equal I thought of something like this

$$
\partial^2_{tt} u = \partial^2_{tt} U(\alpha x + \beta t, \gamma x + \mu t)
$$

My problem is now that $t$ occurs in both arguments of $U$.
In general, how do I differentiate a function of a composition in several variables, i.e. how to determine something like

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(g(x,t), h(x,t))
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By intuition,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(g(x, t), h(x, t)) = f_{y_1}(g(x, t), h(x, t))g_{t}(x, t) + f_{y_2}(g(x, t), h(x, t))h_{t}(x, t).$$
More systematically, we can argue using the chain rule to obtain
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(g(x, t), h(x, t)) = Df(g(x, t), h(x, t))D_t(
\begin{bmatrix}
g(x, t) \\
h(x, t) \\
\end{bmatrix})
= Df(g(x, t), h(x, t))
\begin{bmatrix}
g_t(x, t) \\
h_t(x, t) \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$